# How can I access the parent object from an inner function in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, events, methods, scope, this

I have declared a class in the following way:

```
function maskEditor() {
    this.init();
};

maskEditor.prototype = {
    foo: null,
    container: new createjs.Container(),

    init:function () {
        this.foo = "bar";
        this.container.on("mousedown", this.onMouseDown); // This is just an easeljs event dispatcher
    },

    onMouseDown: function (event) {
        alert(this.foo); // WRONG. 'this' is out of the scope :(
    }
};
```

Long story short: Im using easeljs library, and I have declared an event dispatcher to capture mouse clicks. I need to access the maskEditor object from inside that method. How can I do that?

Comment: Can you make the short story a little longer?

Comment: Sorry, I didnt know how to formulate the question the right way, I see that it is duplicated. The **bind()**  method made the trick :)

Comment: Actually, there is a canonical way of setting the context (and other parameters) in [Container#on](http://www.createjs.com/docs/easeljs/classes/Container.html#method_on) (pass it as the 3rd parameter).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to bind the context to the eventhandler:

```
this.container.on("mousedown", this.onMouseDown.bind(this));
```